# Parent Child List in MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, parent

I'm trying to display a nested Parent \ Child list of products.  My table has an Id field and a ParentId field.  I have the List<> of Product objects and now I want to display it on a view.  I came up with the following solution but I'm sure there is a better one.

My solution:

I know the names of the main products \ groups so while looping through an array of those names, I query the List<> of Products for the Product.Name that == array item.  Once I find it,

I start an un-ordered list

Add my list item

Product.Name

Find any child items by querying the List <> of Products for any records who's ParentId == Product.Id.  If there are some, I pretty much repeat the process but this time using the Child Product as the Parent Product and looking for it's children.
Once there are no more children for a Product, I close the list item  and then close list

Even though this works, right now I know my list will not be deeper than three levels so I only coded for that meaning that the child of say a Great Grand Dad would never be seen.  I would like to make so that it will go deep as it needs to be.  Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you supplied some code showing the models and what you have done so far (controller code and view code)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

In master view, render products with no parent:

```
@Html.Action("DisplayChildren", "ControllerName", new { parentId = null })
```

In partial view, recursively render offspring:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
<ul>
    @foreach (var child in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => child.Name)
            @Html.Action("DisplayChildren", "ControllerName", 
                new { parentId = child.Id })
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

In controller, return only the direct children:

```
public ActionResult DisplayChildren(int? parentId)
{
    var children = GetDirectChildrenOf(parentId);
    if (children.Count() > 0)
        return PartialView(children);
    else return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm still new to mvc so I might have some followup questions but i'll try this out.  Thanks again.